# useProxy per page on puppeteer returns not a function/constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, puppeteer

I am using puppeteer and I am trying to use a proxy per page, and I am using this package called `puppeteer-page-proxy`

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
var useProxy    = require('puppeteer-page-proxy');
var browser     = await puppeteer.launch({});

const page  = await browser.newPage();
useProxy(page, 'http://' + myProxy)
```

Log:

```
useProxyPer[target.constructor.name](target, data);
                               ^
TypeError: useProxyPer[target.constructor.name] is not a function
```

This returns an error as such, which I can't tell why. I found [an issue](https://github.com/Cuadrix/puppeteer-page-proxy/issues/98) which asks this problem, and [a dev](https://github.com/LeM0-Dev/puppeteer-page-proxy) replies with its own package for solution.

Yet If I try that I get exactly the same thing

```js
const useProxy  = require('@lem0-packages/puppeteer-page-proxy');
....
useProxy(page, 'http://' + myProxy)
```

Log:

```
useProxyPer[target.constructor.name](target, data);
TypeError: useProxyPer[target.constructor.name] is not a function
```

Which doesn't fix the problem. A user comments

> This doesn't appear to be fixed to me, same problem in Puppeteer 21.3.x but not in 21.2.x.

If I check my Puppeteer version with `npm -v puppeteer` I get 9.2.0 which is not even close to what that user is referencing. If that is the problem, How do I install Puppeteer 21.2.x? It seem to be only a version issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a setup that worked for me:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const useProxy = require("@lem0-packages/puppeteer-page-proxy");

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const [page] = await browser.pages();
  await useProxy(page, null /* or pass a proxy string; see docs */);
  await page.goto("http://www.example.com");
  console.log(await page.title()); // => Example Domain
  await browser.close();
})();
```

package.json:

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@lem0-packages/puppeteer-page-proxy": "^1.3.3",
    "puppeteer": "^21.2.0"
  }
}
```

(Run `npm i` to install the versions listed above).

Comment: Does my code not work for you? Same error as the original post?

Comment: yes it works.. i have another question which can only be answered by fetching the URL

Comment: Is it a proxy URL or a site URL you want to send? I may not have time today to do an off-site thing, and I generally [charge my freelancer rate](https://www.codementor.io/@ggorlen) if it isn't contributing to a public knowledge resource.

Comment: it is a site URL and I guess I found the solution... YET your profile looks great I noted this down.

Comment: const useProxy = require("@lem0-packages/puppeteer-page-proxy"); it works!